# How to wrap image with text separate in col-6

Tags: html, image, text, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a lot of contents in my paragraph and I need to wrap image with the content.

How can I do this?

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6>
  <img src="something/something.jpg alt="something" />
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6>
  <p>some loooong text</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are those missing " after "col-sm-6 typos?

Comment: please create an image demonstrating what you are looking for

Comment: something like that - http://cdn.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/wrapping-text.jpg

Comment: but the problem is that i need separate text and img in col-sm-6

Comment: you could use CSS Shapes https://drafts.csswg.org/css-shapes/

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use `col-sm-6`, this gives you something similar to [your link](http://cdn.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/wrapping-text.jpg) in the comments:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p>First paragraph...</p>
        <p>Second paragraph....</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="" />
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <p>Third paragraph...</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```